# Detect which emoticon is present in given string

Tags: java, regex, algorithm

I am making a java application and I require to remove the emoticon present with the 'keyword' or 'emotion' which that emoticon is representing....

For example

`I am feeling very happy :)`

should be changed to

`I am feeling very happy smile.`

How can I do it, I tried using regex but I am not able to design generalised regex pattern for this.

Comment: Post your attempt here.

Comment: One thing possible is to include the Emoji codes all together, and parse your string against it. Simple, but should work.

Comment: First of all I have made a hashmap with keys as emoticons and values as the keywords and the regex is "^[:*=;][:D3'cfP]+"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use case you have is optimally solved by using a [*trie*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure to hold all your emoticons. At each step through the string you make one step down the trie (if there's a match for the char). This would allow you to make just one pass through the string to find all occurences of emoticons.

Answer (score 1):

A generalized regex won't really help unless you're swapping all emoticons with a single phrase.  What you need is a dictionary of the form ":)"=>"smile",":("=>"frown".
Once that's complete, you can use String.replace(String, String) and not even worry about a regex.

Comment: How to know which emoticon is present??

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)
<br/>should work.  You'll need exactly 1 search for every emoticon you've decided to recognize.  Pseudo code:
<br/>`foreach (key in emoticon-map) {
originalSentence.replaceAll(key, emoticon-map[key])
}`

Comment: This would work, but would be far from optimal due to constant rescanning of the whole string, every time doing just a small bite of the whole work to be done against each character.

Answer (score 0):

what about using Hashmap to indexing the emoticons? then instead of regex, just perform a search replace!